# Why is the auto layout messing up the sizing?

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

I clicked the add all missing contstraints to my main storyboard, but for some reason one of the buttons is getting stretched. How do I fix this?

[image: Image of how the stretched button looks like]

Comment: have you tried to set compression resistance to required on the headsets image?

Comment: Having Xcode add all missing constraints just means that it guesses. It add constraints that maintain *something* about the current layout, but it might not be maintaining the thing you think is important. You always have to review the constraints and make sure they do what you want. You can't just assume that Xcode will get it right. Probably what Xcode has chosen to maintain is the distances of the two lower images from the superview's edges and each other, not their sizes or aspect ratios.

Comment: Never let Xcode add missing constraints. It never works.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a fixed width and remove the horizontal space to the small logo icon.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this is whole picture. Show behaviour is possible if there is bottom and top constraints set to those elements and interface launched on smaller display. I believe there is messages in console which tell you what auto layout had to break few constraints to satisfy your settings.
Try to lower top and bottom constraint's priority to `999` and it should save them from squeezing on smaller screens.